# How can I multiply time by float?

Tags: python

does anyone know how to multiply time by float? I'm trying to create weekly wage calculator, and I'm stuck on multiplying worked time by hourly rate. Let's say I worked for 14:53 (14 hours and 53 minutes) this week, and my hourly rate is $24.58. How can I calculate how much did I earn this week in total?

I tried this and of course it isn't accurate because hour has 60 minutes, not 100.

```py
rate = float(24.58)
hour = float(input("Enter time: "))
print("Earned: " + str(rate*float(hour)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you supposed to input the time? How would you input 14:53?

Comment: So, what time did you enter?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about maths, not programming.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including input, expected output (correct number), and actual output (incorrect number). You can [edit] the question. It sounds like you're inputting `14.53`, which is incorrect because minutes aren't decimals; that'd be `14.88`. If you want your program to convert `14:53`, that's perfectly valid, you'd just need to parse it and divide the minutes by 60. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Beside the point, but `float(24.58)` is redundant. `24.58` is already a float.

Comment: @wjandrea That's exactly what I asked for. Sorry for unclear question, I'll remember to make my questions more detailed next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You worked 14:53 hours. How many hours is it? It's `14 + 53/60 == 14.8833` hours. Then multiply that by `24.58`:

```
rate = 24.58

# Time as HH:MM
time = input("Enter time: ")

# `time` is a string, so you can split it
hours, minutes = time.split(':')

# Convert `hours` and `minutes` from strings to floats
total_hours = float(hours) + float(minutes) / 60

# Multiply and print
print("Earned:", rate * total_hours)
```